# Asignar manejador de eventos a una colección de elementos HTML dinámico

Tags: javascript, eventos, onclick

estoy realizando una agenda con JS. La interfaz es la siguiente:[image: Interfaz gráfica de la agenda]

La ventana de la izquierda sirve para crear una nueva nota, y la ventana de la derecha muestra la lista de apuntes.
La ventana de la derecha tiene el siguiente código HTML:

```
<div id="buscarApuntes" class="menu">
        <div id="busqueda">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Palabra clave...">

            <input type="date">

            <label for="hecho">Hecho
                <input type="checkbox" id="hecho">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div id="anotaciones">
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Cada vez que se crea una nueva nota, se crea como elemento **li** dentro del **ul**. Quiero asignar un manejador de eventos *onclick()* a cada elemento **li** para que se le asigne o se le borre la clase "hecho". El problema está en que no soy capaz de asignar ese manejador, dejo el código que me da el problema aquí debajo:

```
//obtiene una coleccion de li
let coleccion = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (let elemento of coleccion) {
       elemento.addEventListener("click",tareaRealizada);
}

function tareaRealizada(apunte) {
       apunte.classList.toggle("hecho");
}

/*Se crea HTML dinámico para mostrar una nota en la interfaz*/
visualizarNota(apunte){
    //Crea un elemento <li> y guarda los contenidos en el innerHTML
    //añade el li como hijo del <ul>
    let elementoLi = document.createElement("li");
    elementoLi.innerHTML = apunte.fecha + "<br/>" + apunte.contenido;
    document.querySelector("#anotaciones>ul").appendChild(elementoLi);
 }
```

Comment: indica el código que inserta listas dinámicas a tu `<ul>`

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo ya lo he cambiado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando creas elementos dinámicos no puedes asignarles eventos al cual tienen que escuchar porque la primera vez que se carga el DOM este no los conocen(obvio porque no existen), lo adecuado es que tus elementos dinámicos esten en un contenedor "padre" y a este asignarle el evento que quieres escuchar de sus hijos(dinámicos en este caso) y luego identificar cual hijo emitió el evento para aplicar la lógica que buscas.
Una forma muy sencilla de hacerlo es la siguiente:

```js
/*
* listener al elemento con id="addTask" a su evento click
* crea un elemento <li> y toma el texto del input con id="inputTask"
* para insertarlo dentro del elemento <ul> con id="tasks"
*/
addTask.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let elementoLi = document.createElement("li");
  elementoLi.textContent = inputTask.value
  tasks.appendChild(elementoLi)
})

/*
* listener al elemento <ul> con id="tasks" tomando en la función
* el evento que emite, y destructurando el objeto recibido
* quedandose solo con la propiedad target para luego 
* verificar si el tagName es un LI entonces hacer
* toggle con la clase css "hecho"
*/
tasks.addEventListener('click', function({ target }) {
  if (target.tagName === 'LI') target.classList.toggle("hecho")
})
```

```css
.hecho {
  text-decoration-line: line-through;
}
```

```html
<input id="inputTask">
<button id="addTask">
  add task
</button>

<div id="buscarApuntes" class="menu">
  <div id="anotaciones">
    <ul id="tasks">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido, aunque hay una cosa que no entiendo bien, ¿por qué en la función de tasks pasas el parámetro target?¿Por qué lo pasas entre { }?

Comment: Eso se llama destructuración de un objeto, cuando un evento se emite este envia un objeto a la función del listener, este objeto tiene propiedades y entre ellas una llamada target que es el elemento que emitió el evento. Entonces como solo necesito la propiedad `target` aplico la destructuración de objetos con esa sintaxis `function({ target })` para solo tener esa propiedad dentro de la función. Podrías poner en la función recibir el evento en una variable por ejemplo `function(e)` y hacerle un console.log(e) dentro de la función para que veas las propiedades que trae ese objeto.